# RubyMine dont support rbs

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rbs

I want to try RBS in RubyMine,so I follow this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/rbs.html

but in my RubyMine,rbs not work
[rbs not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRRG2.png)

in video there's new rbs file but no in my RubyMine
[no menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJkuu.png)

my RubyMine version: 2021.3.2
ruby version:3.10
OS:MacOS 12.1

thanks

Comment: Could you record a screencast showing your actions and project's structure?

Comment: my project's structure is same as the video,ans i aslo try a rails project

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour has changed slightly. RBS is bundled and included as an External library unless it’s included in the Gemfile. Features like the “New RBS file” aren't shown unless the user has it in their Gemfile as that means they actually want to use it.

Comment: Thanks  . When I add rbs to the Gemfile,I can see the "New RBS file",but RubyMine still show errors in the rbs file,why?

Comment: What kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

this is the error image,looks like the RubyMine dont recognize rbs file

[image: error image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).